# React app is published but images from the directory (/assets/images/) are missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

My React.js app is published but my images assets in the `images` directory (`/assets/images/`) are not deployed.

Published site's structure:

[image]

After building the application with `npm run build`:

[image]

asset-manifest.json:

[image]

React app structure:

[image]

Comment: We need some code :) Can you show us how you import your images?

Comment: Code should be included as actual code in the [edit] not as images. Very bad idea to post code as an image in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just found your site and checked the source. If you check your rendered page in dev tools, your images are rendered as `<img src="[object Module]">`.

It seems you're using `create-react-app` and you used `require` to import your images. In the latest version of CRA, `require` returns an ES module instead of a string because in `file-loader` the `esModule` option is enabled by default.

So make sure, you import your images in one of these ways:

```js
const image = require('../path/to/image.jpg').default;
// OR
import image from '../path/to/image.jpg';
```

**Edit:**

As you've sent the URL of your repo, I can see that you [import images like this](https://github.com/ismailalabou/developerFolio/blob/master/src/containers/greeting/Greeting.js#L48):

```js
<div className="greeting-image-div">
  <img
    alt="saad sitting on table"
    src={require('../../assets/images/manOnTable.svg')}
  ></img>
</div>
```

As I mentioned above, you either need to get the `default` property of the `require`d module:

```js
<div className="greeting-image-div">
  <img
    alt="saad sitting on table"
    src={require('../../assets/images/manOnTable.svg').default}
  ></img>
</div>
```

...or use `import`:

```js
import manOnTable from '../../assets/images/manOnTable.svg'

// ...

<div className="greeting-image-div">
  <img
    alt="saad sitting on table"
    src={manOnTable}
  ></img>
</div>
```

I personally prefer `import`.

Comment: I updated my post, can u please check it out.

Comment: I've just checked it but what I wanted to see is the way you import the images in your react components.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea where I can find that.

Comment: In your React components' JS files.

Comment: i added a snip of the app structure, so you could point me where to go.

Comment: as a matter of fact, here is the link to to project: https://github.com/ismailalabou/developerFolio

Comment: thank you so much both solutions worked, in order to fix all my import i have to go trough all the code and execute this modification in every file :( , why there is not a way of doing it by just modifying a little piece of code in the the manifest.js file for example (configuration file).